# I have use iframe then some issue when i have use url

Tags: javascript, html, content-security-policy

In header I use

```
    Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
```

HTML

```
    <html>
      <body>
        <iframe src="https://example.com/embed" name="myFrame"></iframe>
        <p><a href="https://example.com/embed" target="myFrame">Video call</a></p>
      </body>
    </html>
```

I want to hit the url on same page.

Please give me some solution for this issue. I have shown the error below.

Error in  console:

> pdfmake.min.js:26 Uncaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as
>   JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in
>   the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'
>   'unsafe-inline'".
>
> ```
>         at new Function (<anonymous>)
>         at new t (pdfmake.min.js:26)
>         at Object.<anonymous> (pdfmake.min.js:12)
>         at Object.<anonymous> (pdfmake.min.js:20)
>         at e (pdfmake.min.js:2)
>         at Object.<anonymous> (pdfmake.min.js:11)
>         at Object.<anonymous> (pdfmake.min.js:11)
>         at Object.<anonymous> (pdfmake.min.js:11)
>         at e (pdfmake.min.js:2)
>         at Object.<anonymous> (pdfmake.min.js:11)
>     t @ pdfmake.min.js:26
>     (anonymous) @ pdfmake.min.js:12
>     (anonymous) @ pdfmake.min.js:20
>     e @ pdfmake.min.js:2
>     (anonymous) @ pdfmake.min.js:11
>     (anonymous) @ pdfmake.min.js:11
>     (anonymous) @ pdfmake.min.js:11
>     e @ pdfmake.min.js:2
>     (anonymous) @ pdfmake.min.js:11
>     (anonymous) @ pdfmake.min.js:11
>     e @ pdfmake.min.js:2
>     (anonymous) @ pdfmake.min.js:7
>     (anonymous) @ pdfmake.min.js:7
>     (anonymous) @ pdfmake.min.js:7
>     (anonymous) @ pdfmake.min.js:7
>     e @ pdfmake.min.js:2
>     (anonymous) @ pdfmake.min.js:2
>     e @ pdfmake.min.js:2
>     (anonymous) @ pdfmake.min.js:2
>     (anonymous) @ pdfmake.min.js:2
>     e @ pdfmake.min.js:2
>     (anonymous) @ pdfmake.min.js:2
>     (anonymous) @ pdfmake.min.js:2
>     e @ pdfmake.min.js:2
>     (anonymous) @ pdfmake.min.js:2
>     (anonymous) @ pdfmake.min.js:2
>     (anonymous) @ pdfmake.min.js:2
>     (anonymous) @ pdfmake.min.js:2
> ```
>
> DevTools failed to parse SourceMap: http://localhost/project/assets/public/bower_components/datatables.net/js/pdfmake.min.js.map
>           teleMERForm?text=aWQ9MQ:85 Refused to load the stylesheet 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700,300italic,400italic,600italic'
>   because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "default-src 'self'". Note that 'style-src-elem' was not explicitly
>   set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Comment: The scripts which are being loaded violate the content-security-policy. So either you have to change the policy, or change how you load the scripts, or what scripts you load. It's unclear how the iframe is related - are these scripts being loaded within the iFrame window, in fact? please clarify.

Comment: Try researching 'not an allowed source of script'

Answer (score 0):

For the EvalError you need to rewrite the usage of Function (and possibly eval, setInterval and setTimeout) as described here https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy. If that is not possible you will need to replace SourceMap or add 'unsafe-eval' exrpession to the script-src directive.

For the stylesheet error you will need to include fonts.googleapis.com to default-src, style-src or style-src-elem (for browsers that understand CSP level 3). Alternatively you can reference and serve the file from self.